# Custom data columns in SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, windows-runtime

A small SQLite database project I'm about to embark on involves tables with data columns that need to be partly defined by the end-user (that is, while the app using the SQLite database is being used by end-user). Assume 4 columns readily defined on creating a table (call this static columns) while additional columns are defined on need-basis by the application (call this dynamic columns). Let further assume that dynamic columns can be created up to a limit of N where N is specified by the app (let's say N = 20).

I know how to add or remove table columns in SQLite. What I am interested in at the moment is to have a good grasp of dealing with column data without trying to reinvent the wheel. I can see the need for dealing with "column data" as opposed to the most common "row data" in database access.

The app is intended to allow the user to configure the order in which data is presented from the dynamic columns. This would essentially mean that there is a need for accessing data columns in a particular sequence, and again I have no problem with this (say based on plain SQL query).

The question is to find out if there is/are recommended practice(s) for dealing with column data. For example, I see the need for in-memory data structure that would allow column data manipulation (swapping, sorting, that sort of thing). Are there well established practices and techniques in this area that I can follow up?

If platform is relevant to narrow down your answer, the app is intended for WinRT with C# programming.